# pg_dump permission denied for relation error for owner user

Tags: postgresql, permissions, role, pg-dump, postgresql-12

I am attempting to dump out a PostgreSQL database with `pg_dump`:

`/usr/bin/pg_dump -f /home/crmpicco/rfc_754622.sql -F c -x -E UTF8 -b --disable-triggers -U root -h tillman.ff1lvb.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com -w rfc_754622 --password`

```
pg_dump: error: query failed: ERROR:  permission denied for relation m_indicator_calc
pg_dump: error: query was: LOCK TABLE public.m_indicator_calc IN ACCESS SHARE MODE
```

I have granted privileges to the `root` user with:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO root;
GRANT SELECT on all tables IN schema public TO root;
```

These are my roles:

```
                                                               List of roles
    Role name    |                         Attributes                         |                          Member of                          
-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------
 rds_ad          | Cannot login                                               | {}
 rds_iam         | Cannot login                                               | {}
 rds_password    | Cannot login                                               | {}
 rds_replication | Cannot login                                               | {}
 rds_superuser   | Cannot login                                               | {pg_monitor,pg_signal_backend,rds_replication,rds_password}
 rdsadmin        | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS+| {}
                 | Password valid until infinity                              | 
 rdsrepladmin    | No inheritance, Cannot login, Replication                  | {}
 root            | Create role, Create DB                                    +| {rds_superuser}
                 | Password valid until infinity                              |
```

The database is owned by "root", so I don't understand why it doesn't have access to dump it out to file.

```
                                             List of databases
               Name               |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
----------------------------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 rfc_754622                       | root     | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =T/root              +
                                  |          |          |             |             | root=CTc/root        +
                                  |          |          |             |             | moodle=CT/root
```